# Strings Split and Join

Tags: go

I'm a `go` novice, I have data as follows `Time Server Type Class Method-Message`. with the help of json field delimiter "|" manage to have the following data `Time|Server|Type|Class|Method-Message` I want to split by - in the forth index which is `|Method-Message` then append a field delimiter "|" then join to end up with the following `Time|Server|Type|Class|Method|Message`.have tried to split the data with `n = s[6 : 6+strings.Index(s[6:], "/")]` what it did was to remove `-Message` then ended up with `Time|Server|Type|Class|Method` then i append a field delimiter then ended up with `Time|Server|Type|Class|Method|Message|` but couldn't append the`-Message` it was removed from the data.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why you are using `strings.Index(s[6:], "/")` when there is no `/` character in your original string, but you can replace the  and `-` characters in a few ways:

With your original attempt of split and join twice:

```
msg := "Time Server Type Class Method-Message"
msg = strings.Join(strings.Split(msg, " "), "|")
msg = strings.Join(strings.Split(msg, "-"), "|")
```

Or slightly more efficiently, by only joining once:

```
msg := "Time Server Type Class Method-Message"
parts := strings.Split(msg, " ")
parts = append(parts[:4], strings.Split(parts[4], "-")...)
newMsg := strings.Join(parts, "|")
```

Or with multiple calls to `strings.Replace`:

```
newMsg := strings.Replace(strings.Replace(msg, " ", "|", -1), "-", "|", -1)
```

Or with a single regular expression:

```
newMsg := regexp.MustCompile(`[ -]`).ReplaceAllString(msg, "|")
```

Comment: JimB  Thanks for correcting me on this line `strings.Index(s[6:], "/"` Thanks

Comment: `strings.Index(s[6:], "-"` I used this method `parts = append(parts[:4], strings.Split(parts[4], "-")...)' and it did everything I wanted, was avoiding to use Strings.Replace because it will replace a string with a string meanwhile the fields are separated by delimiter | in the schema which is not a string.    Thanks JimB